# How to calculate energy (KWh) from Temperature (T),Air quality (Co2), and illumination (lux)?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, temperature, power

I have data of temperature, air quality, and illumination.I want to calculate energy consumption (KWh) from these parameters.My data is shown in the image [image]. Also, examples are also shown in image 2 [image].